# Why do NASCAR (Sprint) cars still use carburetors?

Tags: carburetor

The [wikipedia entry for carburetor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carburetor#History_and_development) tells me that the last US domestic carburetted engines were produced in the early to mid-90's. So why does NASCAR still use them?

Are they easier to build, repair, or maintain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two main reasons:

1. Already some races require restrictor plates to keep the speed down, so swapping out the carburetor for modern fuel injection would increase the need for restriction.
2. It is easier to inspect and monitor a carburetor, therefore it is more fair for each team since it is harder to cheat (or at least easier to get caught).

However, from what I understand they are moving for fuel injection starting in 2012.  Some of the reasons for the move:

- They have developed a "Cheap-proof" unit
- Will allow use of E15 fuel.